# Consulta SQL top(1) con DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito realizar una consulta a una tabla de `SQL Server`, la cual genera los pagos programados para cada cuenta (un pago por mes), es decir, al comprar un producto genera 12 registros de pagos a partir de la fecha que se dio de alta.

Necesito obtener el `ID` del producto y el monto pendiente a la fecha, en pseudocodigo seria algo así:

```
SELECT TOP(1)Monto_Pendiente,ID_Producto 
WHERE FechaPago < GETDATE() WHERE ID_Producto <> ID_Producto
```

Dicho de otra forma obtener obtener el monto actual de todos los productos con determinada característica.

Comment: ¿Necesitas obtener la lista de productos y monto adeudado a la fecha (`FechaPago > GETDATE()`)? ¿Podrías agregar la consulta que has intentado y no anduvo? ¿Como se llama la tabla donde están estos registros y el campo donde se encuentra el monto del pago adeudado?

Comment: Hola! Es necesario que añadas la estructura de la tabla origen, datos de prueba y el resultado deseado

Comment: La condición `WHERE ID_Producto <> ID_Producto` siempre regresará falso. Aparte de que estás repitiendo el WHERE.